# Ant script to modify .java files works in "General" Eclipse project, but not in Maven Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant

I have a relatively simple Ant script `commentOutXmlAnnotations.xml` that edits the contents of Java files in all subdirectories to comment out certain lines via regular expressions:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    name="CommentOutXmlAnnotations"  
    basedir="."  
    default="commentOutXmlAnnotations" >

    <!-- This Ant script comments out the following lines from the Java files in this directory
         and all subdirectories:
        -import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
        -@Xml*

        To run this in Eclipse, right-click on this file and click "Run As->Ant Build".             
     -->

    <target
        name="commentOutXmlAnnotations"        
        description="Run" >
            <replaceregexp
                byline="false"
                flags="g" >

                <regexp pattern="(@Xml[A-Za-z0-9]+(\([^)]+\))?|import javax\.xml\.bind\.annotation\.[A-Za-z0-9.]+;)[ \t]*(\r?\n)" />

                <substitution expression="/*\1*/\3" />

                <fileset dir="." >
                    <include name="*/*.java" />
               </fileset>
            </replaceregexp>        
    </target> 
</project>
```

If I drop `commentOutXmlAnnotations.xml` into a new General Eclipse project with .java files in subdirectories and right-click and do "Run As->Ant Build", everything works fine and the lines in the .java files are commented out.

However, if I drop this `commentOutXmlAnnotations.xml` file into a Eclipse Maven project and try to do the same thing, it seems to execute and I'll get the console output:

```
Buildfile: D:\Eclipse_Juno_SR1_OTP\opentripplanner-pojos-unversioned\commentOutXmlAnnotations.xml
commentOutXmlAnnotations:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 302 milliseconds
```

But the contents of the .java files in the subdirectories don't change.  I think it has something to do with the Maven project directory settings.

How do I configure the project/ant script to execute in the same directory in which it is placed, in an Eclipse Maven project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, stupid mistake.

The above script only searches one directory deep, so it looks like the script didn't have any affect, since all java files had package names longer than one directory.

To search all sub directories multiple levels deep, the `fileset` element should be:

```
<fileset dir="." >
    <include name="**/*.java" />
</fileset>
```